# I want a single template to display different lists of items depending on where I am routed to

Tags: html, ember.js, controller, handlebars.js

I have a table (named Super Table) which includes an `.hbs` file and two controllers for 'superTable' and 'superTables', that can display a list of items using the `{{#each model}}` loop, and that list will show different list items depending on where we are routed.

So say we have a list of USERS and a list of LOCATIONS

```
{{#each model}}
  // this will either be a list of users or a list of locations depending on the route
{{/each}}
```

On a separate page, I have two buttons that will both link to this very template, but will display a different list, depending on where we are currently routed.

```
{{#link-to 'users'}}
  Show list of users
{{/link-to}}

{{#link-to 'locations'}}
  Show list of locations
{{/link-to}}
```

*A little info about the actions I use for these lists in my two controllers for the super table*

my controller uses single actions to handle multiple CRUD events like 'edit' & 'destroy'. That's because I call everything as 'model', which makes it extra important that the models can be subbed out for each other

So I imagine that I will need something that checks the current route when the page is loaded, and then switch out the model that is appropriate for that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a partial template to share templates, or you can do render and pass in a template and model.  Partials just insert the template right into the current template, context and everything.

```
{{partial 'list'}}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jadomuxi/1/edit

Render will create a new controller and use that model as the model for that controller, it will have its own context etc.

```
{{render 'list' model}}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dutidibo/1/edit

Comment: @kingpin2k So if I had two .hbs files for 'users' and 'locations' and in each of those hbs files I added a {{partial 'list'}}. Would both hbs files grab from the list/lists controllers?

Comment: if you did a partial in each it wouldn't use the list controller, it would use whatever controller was in scope where you typed partial (you can think of it as literally just copying and pasting that template into the current template)

Comment: I want to use my list controller for both of these hbs files so that could be a problem. It sounds like I should try using 'render'. Will the new controller created by render inherit the qualities of of the list/lists controllers? Or I could specify in the routes to direct both the users.hbs and locations.hbs to use the list controller

Comment: render will create a new controller each time, but it will be the list controller.

Comment: Then it seems like using a 'partial' might be better substituted with 'render' because I want to use the 'list' controller on all objects that use superTable.hbs. I'll give that a test.

Comment: SOLVED using your render method. @Oliver Also tried using components which worked, but for my solution, I will use render